# Should I upgrade to Maven 3?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Are there any compelling reasons for me to upgrade to Maven 3 immediately? Nothing stands out from the [release notes](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.0/release-notes.html).

Have you upgraded to Maven 3 yet? If so, what benefits did you see?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Maven 3 - Worth it???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157240/maven-3-worth-it). But in short, why don't you just try it? There is nothing to "upgrade", just install Maven 3 along your Maven 2 install, change your `PATH` settings and try it on an existing POM. Personally, the performance boost makes me happy as I wrote in my previous answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have upgraded to maven 3. Everything is backward compatible. I have noticed better performance and clear logging. There aren't any compelling reasons yet. However, maven3 has new build phases that should be able to support better plugins with more control. Why not upgrade if everything will still work?

Answer (score 7):

Speed man, speed :) New Maven runs MUCH faster then Maven2.

Just try it:

```
alias mvn3='M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.0 /opt/apache-maven-3.0/bin/mvn'
```

And execute `mvn3 clean install` in your plain old Maven2 project to feel the difference.