# When should we move to Maven 3?

Tags: java, apache-flex, maven-2, build-automation, flexmojos

Our project badly needs to move to Flexmojos4 to get a fix, but this requires Maven 3.  Our project makes extensive use of Maven and we really love it, but have configured it very heavily.  Between a dozen modules we probably have 50+ pages of XML configuration.

We also use Eclipse and make heavy use of the M2Eclipse plug-in.  We also use the following Maven plug-ins:

- Resources
- BuildNumber
- SQL
- Hibernate3
- Flexmojos
- Assembly
- Jetty
- Cargo
- JAR/WAR

and several others.  Reading [this blog](http://www.sonatype.com/people/category/m2eclipse/) makes me feel like Eclipse Indigo is when it'll all work together. When should we invest the time to make the move?

Comment: you should look into this topic , it would help you in deciding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306579/buildr-gradle-or-wait-for-maven-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact "the move" should actually consist of simply upgrading the maven installation / m2eclipse only. Maven 3 is almost completely backward-compatible with Maven 2.

Check the [compatibility notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html) to make sure you are not breaking something that will need a lot to fix.

Comment: m2eclipse is upgraded as well.

Comment: Update: I tried the upgrade and other than having to fix some problems that maven2 never caught, everything Just Worked.  Frankly, given the complexity of our builds and the extremely complex plugin configuration and use of profiles I am *very* impressed that nothing broke.

Answer (score 2):

> (...) Makes me feel like Eclipse Indigo is when it'll all work together. When should we invest the time to make the move?

No, you can use Maven 3 and Eclipse 3.5 / 3.6 now (I don't even remember when I started to use Maven 3).

First, Maven 3 is backward compatible (see [Maven 3 - Worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157240/maven-3-worth-it)) so, as I commented in [Should I upgrade to Maven 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985520/should-i-upgrade-to-maven-3):

> why don't you just try it? There is nothing to "upgrade", just install Maven 3 along your Maven 2 install, change your PATH settings and try it on an existing POM.

Second, m2eclipse 0.10 uses Maven 3 as embedded version for a long time (for dependency resolution even if you declare an "external" install) and is thus already Maven 3 ready. Just add the final version of Maven 3.0 as external install and there you go.

To sum up: Maven 3 is totally usable, I almost had nothing to change in my poms (only a few things to *fix* them thanks to the better reporting of Maven 3), it just works inside Eclipse and it builds faster. Just try it.

PS: I use the script attached to [MNG-2730](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2730) to switch between the maven versions I have on my machine, if required.