# switching to maven3

Tags: maven, maven-3

We have several enterprise projects on maven2, do you think it would be a good idea to switch now to maven 3?

I heard the migration is not hard but there are not big improvements unless you're going to use the parallel builds. But our build machine is already almost choked up so I don't think we can use it.

Has someone experienced problems or big improvements?

Comment: IMO migration to maven-3 is worth. Checkout the features that maven-3 offers...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157240/maven-3-worth-it

Comment: Check if you use unique snapshot versions or not, the non-unique are dropped in m3, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275466/how-do-you-deal-with-maven-3-timestamped-snapshots-efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing is to do some test builds with Maven 3 to see if there a any big problems. If not it's not a big deal. Improvments are there, cause Maven 3 is usually a little bit faster than the same build in Maven 2. So it might be worth to analyze it in detail.