# Can maven3 runtime execute maven2 compatible pom.xml files

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

Some of our new projects have been migrated to maven3 and some of the older projects are still using the maven2 compliant pom.xml files.

Can maven3 runtime execute maven2 compatible pom.xml files also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maven 3 is mostly compatible with maven 2 configuration. But there is still some incompatibilities.

For a full list you should check [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html) there is also sometime problems with plugins (as Torsten suggested).

---

**Resources:**

- [Maven 3.x Plugin Compatibility Matrix](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Plugin+Compatibility+Matrix)

**On the same topic:**

- [switching to maven3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258160/switching-to-maven3)

Answer (score 1):

Typically yes, but it may depend on the plugin version you are using.

Please note that e.g. the maven site plugin is different for maven 2 and maven 3 or some options of the maven enforcer plugin are no longer valid for maven 3. There might be others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.
At first you may be alarmed by the fact that it reports a bunch of warnings and sometimes refuses to build before you take care of the problems, but this is actually better for you as (if you run into this) it simply tells you what was wrong with your project so far.

Other than that, the site plugin is completely re-written and you need to use the version for Maven 3. (Check [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-and-site-plugin.html))