# Maven 3 documentation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-3

I can't find any good documentation for the new version of maven (Maven 3)
There are few blog entries that are mostly related to Maven 3 Beta.

Do you know of any official/unofficial documentation or tutorial for Maven 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Maven3 Plan](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Maven3Plan), you get the **[Maven3 wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x)**, which is the closest piece of "maven 3-specific" documentation out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation on the official website right here http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/index.html

The documentation is on the left hand side.

Comment: That is not maven documentation, That is just the project diagram. see http://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html for maven 2 documentation. I don't think there is something similar to that for maven 3

Comment: well actually on right hand side your have more documentation options as it stands. They are still working on it. Plus they made a lot of efforts keeping as backwards compatible as possible so the maven 2 documentation should indeed work.

Comment: Fair enough but is there any doc for maven 3 somewhere? If all we can do with maven 3 for now is to run maven 2 poms then what is the point of upgrading to maven 3? I have been monitoring maven 3 website for the past couple of month but I don't see any progress on documentation, is there a wiki or something?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for user documentation, not the developer/plugin model/api documentation (in which case his answer would have been quite helpful).

Answer (score 0):

The current Maven 3 documentation is on the [main Maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html).  It is still getting updated however, and I'm sure would appreciate help with any inconsistencies that you find.  Because of the amount of work that went into making Maven 3 backwards compatible, most of the documentation is still valid.  The [compatibility notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html) do a good job highlighting the differences.

If you're already using Maven 2 and are looking for reasons to upgrade, see the [stack overflow question on whether Maven 3 is worth it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157240/maven-3-worth-it).

Also, note that due to the nature of betas/alphas/release candidates, the documentation shouldn't change much between versions, so all the blog posts on pre-release Maven 3s should be pretty much correct.

Comment: The link that you provided for main maven site links to maven 2 documentations.

Comment: Some parts of it may still reference Maven 2.  However, I'd still say that the main Maven site I linked to has documentation for Maven 3.  The Technical Project and Settings Descriptor links go to files in the Maven 3 docs.  The Mojo API specification talks about both Maven 3 and Maven 2 and things that changed between them.  Intro to profiles has Maven 3 specific docs.

Answer (score -1):

On a sidenote, I can tell you what is **not** Maven 3 documentation: [Apache Maven 3 Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849512442), shiny new from print this month. It does not talk about sophisticated native americans cooking recipes, but neither does give you anything useful specifically related to Maven 3. Learn from my painful experience and stay away from it (still a decent book on Maven in general, though).

Comment: In my opinion the fact that there is no online documentation even after a year seems like a good reason to consider Gradle for new projects.