# scope "provided" gives install error in maven

Tags: maven

I am trying to install a Maven distribution from sourceforge (jtmt.sf.net) which provides a POM. Hoewever

```
mvn install
```

throws the error:

```
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin[org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty6-plugin].depende
ncies.dependency.scope' for org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee_1.4_spec:jar
 must be one of [compile, runtime, system] but is 'provided'. @ line 653, column
 20
```

The pom contains the code:

```
      <!-- For web development with Jetty6 -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty6-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
          <port>8081</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        </connector>
      </connectors>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee_1.4_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

I am assuming the POM worked in the past though the project is somewhat dormant now.

Is there some switch I should set when installing? (I am using mvn 3.0.3). FWIW the distrib has checked out a very large number of libraries in `lib/` .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The project was probably working with Maven 2. Maven 3 is much more picky about scopes in plugins, and scope `provided` is no longer allowed in plugin dependencies. You can try:

- removing the dependency entirely and rebuilding (scope `provided` means something should already make it available anyway)
- removing just the `<scope>` tag (to make it a simple `compile` dependency)
- if nothing helps, you can try building it with Maven 2

The reason `provided` is now disallowed in plugins is that `provided` is really for dependencies provided by the environment (e.g. app server) at runtime. Jetty is a special case - it's an app server used frequently as a plugin.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I think you are right about the maven version. I now have more errors (about the dependencies not being resolved although the jars are in the lib directory). Is there a way to set a switch on maven to run maven2 or do I have to download and install maven2?

Comment: The dependency system for M3 is completely new (they now use a separate library called Aether), so such a switch is unlikely to exist.

Comment: Thanks. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157240/maven-3-worth-it it was stated that Maven3 is backwards compatible but maybe that is optimistic.